# WPF dynamic binding of a control property to another control property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a question - I was coding happily a quick little feature to an app, which was a simple comparison output window.
Basically, user clicks a button and I generate a window with a datagrid of two columns of data.

It's all great and a five minutes code living inside one method with no unnecessary reference to anything else. The only problem I encountered was when I wanted to add a TopMost checkbox to this window.
How do I bind the IsChecked property of the box to the TopMost property of the window?

```
        var checkbox = new CheckBox();
        checkbox.Name = "cb";
        checkbox.Content = "Top most";


        var grid = new DataGrid();
        grid.ItemsSource = wcList;
        grid.Margin = new Thickness(5);

        var panel = new StackPanel();
        panel.Children.Add(checkbox);
        panel.Children.Add(grid);

        var win = new Window();

        //Binding b = new Binding("cb");
        //b.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
        //b.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;

        //win.SetBinding(Window.TopmostProperty, b);

        win.Title = "WordCount comparison";
        win.Content = panel;
        win.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
        win.Icon = this.Icon;

        win.Show();
```

This was supposed to be a 5-minutes one-off method, which is why I don't want to go as far as adding any xaml or properties into the code.

Cheers
Bartek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other way around as you tried (in the commented code):

```
   checkbox.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("Topmost") { Source = win });
```

just after you instantiated your win variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, Alek. Works perfectly - that will be a useful bit;)